# Is there a single-word adjective that has the meaning of "having good sense of rhythm"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I would like to know is there a single-word adjective that has the meaning of "having good sense of rhythm"?

I am trying to find an adjective to describe the characteristics of a lady, who is good in singing and dancing. In my opinion, she has very good sense of rhythm. This word will serve as the heading of a paragraph that describes her and her work. As I would like to be consistent with the heading of other paragraphs, such as "versatile", "charming" and "elegant", I would like to find a single-word adjective for such purpose.

I believe "rhythmic" or "rhythmical" may not work in my case. As in dictionary.com, "rhythmical" means (1) periodic, as motion, or a drumbeat, 
(2) having a flowing rhythm, (3) of or relating to rhythm; and "rhythmic" means "rhythmical". None of them have the meaning of "having good sense of rhythm".

Comment: the notion of "groove" seems to loosely fit the idea of being rhythmic; someone who can "groove" with the music understands and moves to its rhythm.

Comment: Hi GreenPenguin welcome to English Language & Usage. Unfortunately there are a few problems with this question that need to be fixed before we are able to help you find the best answer, and the question may be closed until improved for that reason. One is that single word requests require an exemplary sentence; another is that we need you to show us you have checked a thesaurus for synonyms that might match better and finally, you also need to explain why the closest alternatives you've considered won't work. Otherwise, we won't have any notion of what kind of word you do want to be helpful.

Comment: 'Musical' could work if you are referring to a person.

Comment: People say, "José can keep the beat" or "can keep a steady beat."  "José can really swing" or "can make it swing."  In the right context, "José is solid."

Comment: depending on the writing style, "Groovy" ( @socrates ) may actually fit. It is a little dated and a little informal however. Since this is a header, a little hyperbole or departure from expectation can be reigned in or clarified by the text that follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looking for an adjective, I might suggest **metronomic**.

https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=metronomic

> 1. Of or relating to a metronome
> 2. Mechanically or unvaryingly regular in rhythm

The word is not specific to people, but since the question only specifies that the word means "having a good sense of rhythm," it seems appropriate, and it could describe a person or their activity.

Comment: A metronome marks only the beat and tempo, not the rhythm.  Rhythm has to do with the pattern of stressed and unstressed beats.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps something simple, such as **rhythmist**, defined by [American heritage dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=rhythmist) as

> One who is an expert in or has a keen sense of rhythm.

Comment: Hi vickyface. I'm sorry for the vote against your answer, but the questioner is specifically looking for an adjective, and your reference only lists the word rhythmist as a noun. Do you have evidence supporting the notion that rhythmist may also be an adjective?

Comment: @Tonepoet oops.